# Change Woocommerce SKU if product is on backorder (add suffix to SKU)

Tags: woocommerce

I'm trying to change a Woocommerce SKU (most likely add a suffix) if a product is on backorder. Reason being is accounting related with integration to Xero which doesn't have a facility for backorders.

So if stock is 10 SKU = PRODABC
but if stock is =<0 then SKU = PRODABC-BK

I've searched high and low for a solution but cannot find anything.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: THe SKU should change in the Order line item when a backorder is placed or the Product itself when the stock goes to 0?

Comment: SKU is part of product meta not the order and therefore changing it in product should update it in the order too if im not mistaken. So even if you change it using woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item i think will reset once you update product. Maybe push the question in https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/woocommerce/ for confirmation ?

Comment: Ah yes I hadn't considered that it will change past order SKUs too, that would create an issue... Hmm, may have to come up with another solution